# Incorrect URL redirect on Facebook iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, url, unicode, arabic

We have been having an issue since the latest release of Facebook iOS app this week: links on our Facebook page facebook.com/ainelaql redirects to a 404 page when accessed from within the mobile app. When accessed through a browser the links work just fine.
The URLs have Arabic Unicode characters that are %encoded, so there might be something about how the app resolve these that is driving this behavior.

Did anybody else face similar issues, and how did they resolve it?

For future posts we are taking out the Arabic characters, but we have many past links that we can't simply change now.

Appreciate all thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we are facing the same problem.

thats really strange, seems facebook pushed their latest release impacting URLs with arabic encoded characters.

we are currently using shortening service for all new posts, but still looking for a solution to resolve URLs for the existing shared posts.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @JohnBarça + others in the Low Quality Posts queue: please read the question **carefully** before voting to delete this post. The question is asking whether anyone else is facing this issue, and how they resolved it; this answer seems to cover both of those, so I'm not sure how it "doesn't really answer the question".

Comment: Does any else has this problem and maybe a resolution?

We are also having the same issue with Greek unicode %encoded characters.
When viewed from facebook iOS or Android apps they both break.

I have tried to debug this by looking at webserver logs (requested URLs) and it seems that from mobile the encoded string is completely different.